# Plastic SCM Repository Permission Inheritance/Assignment

Tags: plasticscm

I have been evaluating it for some time, testing different scenarios and trying different configurations.  During this time, I have deleted and recreated my repositories a number of times.  Each time, I have had to go back and reassign all of the permissions to each repository.

Currently, I have decided to use a single repository for common code, and then a separate repository for each product that will be produced.

Now, I am just about to take the leap and start using Plastic SCM in earnest.  But before I do that, I have a question: is there a way to inherit/assign permissions on a repository from another repository?  E.g. I set up all permissions on 'Repo A', and then inherit/assign those same permissions on 'Repo B'.

I am sure that I will be adding more repositories as we produce more products, and I would like to find the easiest way bring them online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a set of permissions for the repository server by right clicking a repository and clicking on `Repository Server` permissions:

[image: RepositoryServerPermissions]

Then all the repositories will inherit permissions from the repository server.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is sufficient for now.  However, at some point I expect that I will have repositories that have the same permissions as other repositories, but not _all_ repositories will have the same permissions.  Is there any other way to inherit repository permissions?

Comment: I recommend you to setup a script that set some permissions to a repository using the `cm acl` command. Type `cm help acl` to see how the command works.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  However, I'm having trouble with the syntax for the `-inherit` parameter.  I've tried `cm acl -group=MyGroup rep:RepoB@MyServer:8084 -inherit=rep:RepoA@MyServer:8084` but I get "The object you have specified cannot inherit from the parent object. They are not compatible."  I've also tried switching RepoA and RepoB on the command line above, but I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid that a repository cannot inherit from another one, so maybe the script solution is the best here.